# How does extrapolation for spline in Matlabs interp2 works?

Tags: c#, matlab, image-rotation, math.net, bilinear-interpolation

I know there has already been a lot of questioning about spline extrapolation in Matlab. I have an example where this works great in 2D and I want to understand this behaviour to programm it in C# using Math.Net. Here is my example:

```
matrix = zeros(128,128);
barWidth = 10;

%Calculate Midpoints
midpointX = floor(size(matrix,2)/2) + 1;
midpointY = floor(size(matrix,1)/2) + 1;

matrix(midpointY-barWidth:midpointY+barWidth,:) = 1;

% Windowing (I know it could be shortened...)
distanceMatY = -midpointY+1:midpointY-2;
distanceMatY = abs(repmat(distanceMatY',1,size(matrix,2)));
Factor = 0.5*(cos(pi*distanceMatY/barWidth)+1);
index = distanceMatY > barWidth;
Factor(index) = 0;
matrix = matrix.*Factor;

% Rotate matrix
alpha = 30 * pi/180;
y = -midpointY+1:midpointY-2; y = y'; 
x = -midpointX+1:midpointX-1;     %set new COS for rotation in Midpoint
xRot = x*cos(alpha) - y*sin(alpha) + nMP;  %Determine X and Y matrices for
yRot = x*sin(alpha) + y*cos(alpha) + mMP;  %Roatation with angle alpha

rotMatrix = interp2(matrix,xRot,yRot,'linear');      %Interpolate rotated matrix
```

I have a matrix of zeros with a bar over the whole length in the middle.
[image: Input Matrix]
I applied a Hann Window to the bar to smooth the edges and then rotated the matrix by 30 degrees with bilinear interpolation.
[image: Rotated Matrix bilinear]
Now I have values outside the boundaries which are set to NaN. I could set all the NaN values to zero but what I really want is that the bar will be extended automatically. Now I could pad the matrix before rotation and cut it again after rotation to the input matrix size.
Much easier it is to just use `interp2(matrix,xRot,yRot,'spline')` and the rotated matrix looks exactly as I want for each angle.
[image: Rotated Matrix spline]
How does the 2D spline interpolation does it and is there a way to program that manually?

Comment: This page explains it in detail: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation — also, there are links to implementations at the bottom.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the link. It helps to understand why the values stay the same at the end of the bar and extrapolation works. If I understand it correctly - to programm the 2D-Interpolation I need to assemble and solve a equation system. Let's say I already have 1D-Splines for each row and column of a matrix. Could I also directly use these splines to interpolate for any x-/y-Value of this matrix?

Comment: 2D interpolation usually works by first interpolating each row to the new grid, then in the result, interpolate each column to the new grid. I don’t know if there is a shortcut that would allow you to use splines for each row and column of the input image to directly obtain the interpolated value anywhere. I’ve always preferred using a [cubic spline kernel for interpolation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation#Bicubic_convolution_algorithm) (where you only need 16 input values in 2D to find one interpolated value).